# Re-heat Sous Vide Roast Beef

Tags: sous-vide, reheating, searing, roast-beef

I've just completed a 6 hr Beef Roast (sear and sous vide), when we collectively realised we can't eat it today.

What's the best way of keeping it for the next day without drying it out?

My current thinking is:

- Leave it in the bag (with all the juices)
- Sous vide again tomorrow for 3 hrs to bring the heat back

If it helps:

- 2.5kg uncooked weight (inc fat cap)
- Seared in hot pan with garlic, rosemary, salt, and pepper.
- 6 hrs at 60c

**EDIT**

The second cook really made the initial garlic and rosemary flavours permeate the joint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leave sealed in bag, but be sure to cool as quickly as possible (ice bath and stirring).  Refrigerate.  Reheat, sous vide, in bag.  It will take at least 3 hours to reheat. You will need the time it takes for the center to be up to your desired temp (I assume pretty close to 60C).

Comment: Amazing, thankyou! I'll try that tomorrow and follow up.

Comment: And, of course, the overall goal is to cross the "danger zone" (10-40°C) as quickly as possible, in both directions.

Comment: @moscafj Worked like a charm. It came out perfectly, thankyou!

Comment: @AnoE ...that's new to me, what does that mean?

Comment: @Kieron, the reason we either cool or heat stuff is because most evil things cannot survive past 52-53°C or so (that's why we sous vide in that region, mostly); and most evil things *can* survive at low temperatures (4-7°C for your regular fridge) but multiply very slowly. In the medium range, especially at 20-35 or so, most evil things don't die but reproduce the more quickly the warmer it gets. So you want to be either at low or at high(ish) temperatures as much as possible.

Comment: @AnoE every day is a school day, Thankyou!